# How to print div element with canvas inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that contains div elements I want to grab and print. And inside the div there is a canvas that contain a barcode image, and I want the image to be printed as well.

Here is the page code:

```
<div data-v-78bfab32="" class="trx-slip" data-testid="trx-print-slip-2892470852">
<div class="row"> SOME LOGO HERE</div>
    <div data-testid="trx-info-booking-code">
    <hr>
        <div class="row section-logistic-booking">
        <canvas data-testid="trx-barcode" class="barcode" width="166" height="65"></canvas>
            <div>TEXT 1
            </div>
                <div class="c-trx-slip--font-large">TEXT 2
                </div>
                <div class="c-trx-slip--notice-outset">
                    <div class="u-txt--upcase u-txt--bold">TEXT 3 
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the preview of that page with CSS:

[image]

However, every time I try to grab the ".trx-slip" element, it wouldn't grab the image on the canvas.

This is the script i use to grab and print the element:

```
function printAll(){
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".trx-slip");
if(!containers){
    alert("Nothing to print");
}
var content = "";
for(var i =0; i < containers.length; i++){
    var addEOL = i + 1 != containers.length;
    content = content + addWrapperDiv(containers[i].outerHTML, addEOL);
}
print(content);
}

function print(content){
var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print', 'height=600,width=800');
mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>');
mywindow.document.write(getCssPart());
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write(content);
mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

mywindow.document.close();
mywindow.focus();
mywindow.onload = function(){
mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();
}
}
function addWrapperDiv(content,  addEOL = true){
content = '<div class=".trx-slip">' + content + '</div>';
if(addEOL){
    content = content + '<p style="page-break-after: always" />';
}
return content;
}

function getCssPart(){
var links = document.querySelectorAll("link,style");
var link = "";
for(var i =0; i < links.length; i++){
    link += links[i].outerHTML.replace(/@page[^}]+}/gm,'');
}
return link;
}
printAll();
```

How to get the image on the canvas to print as well?

Comment: So by print you just want the canvas on another page, or you want your Client to be able to print it on their printer? Or you really want to force a download, on the Client, of an image of the canvas?

Comment: By print, I mean to be printed on printer, but yes I need the canvas to be available on new opened window / another page first.

Comment: In that case, I would do `canvasElement.toBlob()`. Send it to the Server via `FormData`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace canvas for img. With src equals to original dataUrl you will transfer drawing to the preview page and will be able to print it.

Keep in mind that toDataURL method may throw an exception if drawing is origin-unclean.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-todataurl

In your printAll function collect clones of containers and replace canvas with img

```
var containers = [...document.querySelectorAll(".trx-slip")]
                         .map((el)=>{ 
                            var cl = el.cloneNode(true);
                            var cvs = cl.querySelector(".barcode");
                            var dataUrl = cvs.toDataUrl();
                            var img = document.createElement("img");
                            img.src = dataUrl;
                            // set size?
                            cvs.parentElement.replaceChild(img,cvs);
                            return cl;
                         });
```

then continue with your code.

Comment: I tried that but the print window won't appear. I opened the console and got error message : Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function at line 3.

Comment: use `[...document.querySelectorAll(".trx-slip")].map...`. Indeed NodeList has no map method.

Comment: Well, it needs ".toDataURL()", just a little mistype there, and the print window is showing but the barcode image however, is not. I can see the URL is some base64 image data (data:image/png;base64) but i don't understand why it is not showing in new window even if I type it in the address bar, it only shows a transparent image

Answer (score 0):

Edit the css style:

```
@media print {}
```

then you can write

```
window.print()
```